# Free and Malloc in a Loop - Correct Way to Free Memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, malloc

I have the below loop (code simplified) :

```
for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {

self.array[y].numbers = [self getNumberData:source objectPass:object];

}
```

This calls the get NumberData method. In this code a malloc method is used, e.g :

```
object->item1 = malloc(sizeof(Class) * object->item2);
```

My question is how do I correctly free up the malloced memory ?

The self.array[y].numbers is a C struct.

Can I just put free (array) in the dealloc method ?

Thank you.

Comment: The rule is you need 1 call to `free` for each call to `malloc`. If you `malloc` data in a loop then you will need to free data in the same kind of `loop` in `dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks Joe. How do I keep track of what to release in dealloc ?

Comment: You only show an example of `object->item1`. That means your `dealloc` will at least need `free(object->item1)`. If you `malloc`'d each `numbers` item then you need to also `free` each numbers item.

Comment: Right but how do I store a reference to object->item1 ? I assume I need to do that, and then add the reference to a list so that I can free (in this case) all 20 mallocs ?

Comment: If you post a code example of just how you are `malloc`ing the data I will post an answer of how your `dealloc` should look.

Comment: Joe - appreciate your help. I have put the two methods above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the pointer returned by `malloc` to `free`.

So, if you've `malloc`ed up the whole array of structs in one swell foop, you can (and must) `free` the whole thing, as well.

If you've `malloc`ed each struct individually, you must `free` each, as well.